# Discrete math: number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> Prove that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $n\ge2$, $n$ has a prime factor

So I have the base case $n=2$ verified to have a prime factor, $2=\underbrace{(2)}_{\text{prime factor}}\cdot 1$

Now what I did was split $n$ into two intervals, the even and odd numbers. With $k\in\mathbb{N}$ taking $n=2k$ I have a prime factor of at least 2 for all $k$, therefore all even $n$ contains a prime factor. Taking $n=2k+1$ I have $n=2(k+1/2)$. Since we have a prime factor of $2$ here as well, then there exists at least a prime factor $2$ for all odd $n$. Therefore every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ contains at least 1 prime factor

Is this a strong enough argument?

Comment: $(k+1/2)$ is not an integer. As a result, no odd numbers have a prime factor of $2$.

Comment: $k+1/2$ is not an integer, but we already know $n$ is a positive integer, so then we have that n is a factor of at least 1 prime number times some non-integer. There being a non-integer doesn't negate that a prime factor exists, right? 

I was told to do it by cases, so a case where there are prime factors and another where there aren't, but i'm not following that version very well at the moment

Comment: An integer $x$ is a factor of an integer $y$ if there exists some *integer* $z$ such that $y=xz$. If you omit the requirement that $z$ is an integer, then *every* nonzero integer is a factor of *every other integer*, which would make the concept rather pointless.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense now

Comment: Hint: the least factor $> 1$ is prime (there is at least one factor $>1$ of $n$, namely $n$ itself, which is the least $\iff n$ is prime).

Answer (score 1):

This is of course complete nonsense; an odd number does not have a prime factor $2$. This is the very defnition of being a number being odd. The problem is that $k+\tfrac12$ is not an integer.

Instead you could prove this by induction. You have already shown the base case. Now if every integer up to $n$ has a prime factor, then either:

1. We can write $n=a\times b$ with $a\leq b<n$. Then $b$ has a prime factor, hence so does $n$.
2. We cannot write $n=a\times b$ with $a\leq b<n$. Then $n$ is prime.